# jQuery html() doesn't complete

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a utility function to insert HTML into a div and then call a javascript initializer function that attaches event handlers to various elements in the inserted HTML.  The functions works great for 90% of cases but periodically fails in the jquery html() call below.  When it fails, the HTML is inserted properly but the code on the next line is never reached.

```
 function loadSection(id, url, initializer = null, param = null) {
        const $div = $('#' + id);
        return $.ajax({
            method: 'GET',
            url: url,
        })
            .done(function (html) {
                $div.html(html);
                if (initializer) { // This line is never reached.
                    initializer(param);
                }
            });
    }
```

The same failure occurs if I use $div.empty().append(html) instead of $div.html(html) so the problem isn't in the html() function itself. In fact, if I step through the html() code, it executes this.empty().append(value) and never returns to the calling function.

The html that is inserted may contain  to set variable values but does not call any javascript functions directly.

I've done a pretty exhaustive search of StackOverflow and the web but have come up empty. I've also traced through the jQuery code but couldn't identify the issue.  Can anyone tell me why this is failing?

---

Answers to some of the questions:

- It IS deterministic.  The failure cases always fail and vice versa.
- I know the code succeeded because code execution gets to $div.html(html).  And the html returned in the GET is correct.
- Example of how this is called:

  function loadNewContracts() {
  loadSection('prospector-newContracts', '../newContracts', initNewContracts);
  }
- The initializers are different for every section.  The key points is that the initializer is NEVER called.
- The correct initializer IS being passed into the function and does exist.
- The only  tags in the HTML set variable values.  No js functions are called.  Calls that succeed also set variable values.  There are NO loops in the  tags.
- The $div variable DOES exist in all cases.

Comment: Is it not deterministic? Does it fail AND succeed randomly with the same data supplied?

Comment: how you come to know that your code succeeded and come inside `done()`. Also did you checked your browser console? is there any error?

Comment: If the markup is inserted, it works. Show us how you're calling this, and what `initializer` does

Comment: Have you tried logging what initializer is before the if?

Comment: That's not what I asked.  Have you logged the value of initializer before the if to assert that it is not falsey.

Comment: If there are any scripts in the HTML, `$div.html(html)` will execute them. If there's an infinite loop in the script you'll never get to the `if (initializer)` line.

Comment: When it calls `this.empty().append(value)`, it must be going into a loop executing the `<script>` tags. You can click on the pause button in the debugger, and it will show you where in the JS you are. That should help track this down.

Answer (score 0):

Barmar was close and gave me the idea to figure this one out.  The js variables being set in the html are generated in a jinja2 template.  A non-existent value was being passed to the template so the script ended up looking like ...

```
var currentValue = ;
```

... so the js fails while loading the html. Another one failed in an similar manner.  These failed because of recently introduced bug in the server code.

Obvious in retrospect but I overlooked it because you can't break on the js in the .  Thanks, Barmar!